# How to upload a big file with AsiHttpRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use ASIFormDataRequest to upload my file to server.

I convert the file to a NSData object first. But when my file is bigger than 2M, my app always down in upload process.

I know it is a memory issue. But I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to NSData. You can directly set the file as post value.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Or

```
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

If you are uploading large files I would suggest you to use a UIProgressIndicator so you keep the user in the loop about the progress.

To learn more about ASIHTTPRequest see [How to use](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

Hope this solves your issue.

Cheers